# Why my Singleton is synchronized but it gets created many times?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intentservice, android-livedata

For some reason my singleton Repository is created many times from background threads, the synchronized should have helped though. Could anyone help? I will provide code fragments and github link if needed.

My IntentService class:

```
  @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "ArticleIntentService - onHandleIntent");


        LiveData<List<Article>> liveArticles = ArticleRepository.getInstance(getApplication())
                .loadFromNetwork(PAGE_NUMBER, PAGE_SIZE);
        PAGE_NUMBER++;
        liveArticles.observeForever(articles -> {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "onStartJob - onChanged!!!!!!");
//                liveArticles.removeObserver(this);
            NotificationUtils.showNotification(context, articles.get(0).getSectionName(), articles.get(0).getWebTitle());

        });

    }
```

My Repository:

```
public static ArticleRepository INSTANCE;

public static synchronized ArticleRepository getInstance(Application application){
    if(INSTANCE == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "ArticleRepository getInstance is NULL");
        return  new ArticleRepository(application);
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}

private ArticleRepository(Application application) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ArticleRepository constructor");
    mContext = application;
    mArticles = new MutableLiveData<>();
    ArticleRoomDatabase db = ArticleRoomDatabase.getInstance(application);
    mArticleDao = db.articleDao();
}
```

Comment: I guess you are not initializing public static ArticleRepository INSTANCE; in your getInstance method your just returning new instance everytime.

Comment: What would it mean to call your `getInstance` method with a different `Application` instance? You should either return a single instance per application, or throw an exception.

Comment: As a sidenote, let me recommend you to simply use a `enum` if you want to create a Singleton. It's inherintly threadsafe and much easier to test and maintain. It's generally considered the best way to create a Singleton.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never assign `INSTANCE`:

```
public static synchronized ArticleRepository getInstance(Application application){
    if(INSTANCE == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "ArticleRepository getInstance is NULL");
        INSTANCE = new ArticleRepository(application);
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}
```